# Create a folder if it doesn't already exist

Tags: php, wordpress, directory

I've run into a few cases with WordPress installs with [Bluehost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluehost) where I've encountered errors with my WordPress theme because the uploads folder `wp-content/uploads` was not present.

Apparently the Bluehost [cPanel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel) WordPress installer does not create this folder, though [HostGator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HostGator) does.

So I need to add code to my theme that checks for the folder and creates it otherwise.

Comment: `if (!file_exists('path/to/directory')) {
    mkdir('path/to/directory', 0777, true);
}`

Answer (score 1512, accepted):

Try this, using [mkdir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php):

```
if (!file_exists('path/to/directory')) {
    mkdir('path/to/directory', 0777, true);
}
```

Note that `0777` is already the default mode for directories and may still be modified by the current umask.

Comment: You missed the 'recursive' flag - see Satish's answer.

Comment: is_dir() is bit faster, than file_exists()

Comment: @YuryPliashkou Yeah maybe, but it doesn’t work if there’s already a *file* with that name.

Comment: question here: so if there'd be a file named 'directory' in path/to , is_dir would return true, but file_exists would return false?

Comment: @IgorLacik No, `file_exists` would also return true.

Comment: `file_exists` — Checks whether a file or directory exists  
`is_file` — Tells whether the filename is a regular file  
`is_dir` — Tells whether the filename is a directory

Comment: The first comment "You missed...". It's not necessary a recursive flag, the `true` after `0777` means recursive, parameteres is `$pathname`, `$mode` and `$recursive`, (set recursive to `true`, no flags needed)

Comment: Note that when using the recursive flag. The mode only applies to the deepest folder in the path. You will have to do chmod to the parent directories to set the modes manually, unless you are using defaults and good with it.

Comment: In case you create a folder and not file, I don't see the necessity to use `file_exists`. Also it may be even a bad idea, because there's no reason not to have a file and a folder with the same name. Creating a folder then could be blocked by a file.

Comment: Let's do it more with less:
if (!file_exists('path/to/directory')) mkdir('path/to/directory', 0777, true);

Comment: 0777 permissions allow everyone to access/read/write the directory. This is not what we want for upload directory in the web server. 

$path_to_directory = 'path/to/directory';
if (!file_exists($path_to_directory) && !is_dir($path_to_directory)) {
    mkdir($path_to_directory, 0644, true);
}
0644 are the right permissions for uploads directory because we do not usually want uploaded on the server to be executed there.

true is the third parameter for setting recursive property to true or false. It allows the creation of nested directories specified in the pathname.

Comment: note the lack of '/' before and after 'path/to/directory' ....

Comment: Is there a way to do it without a race condition? The directory could be created by a concurrent process between the `file_exists` and `mkdir` call.

Answer (score 181):

Here is the missing piece. You need to pass 'recursive' flag as third argument (boolean true) in [mkdir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) call like this:

```
mkdir('path/to/directory', 0755, true);
```

Comment: the 'recursive' flag being the boolean 3rd argument `true`

Answer (score 76):

Use a helper function like this:

```
function makeDir($path)
{
     $ret = mkdir($path); // use @mkdir if you want to suppress warnings/errors
     return $ret === true || is_dir($path);
}
```

It will return `true` if the directory was successfully created or already exists, and `false` if the directory couldn't be created.

A **better** alternative is this (shouldn't give any warnings):

```
function makeDir($path)
{
     return is_dir($path) || mkdir($path);
}
```

Comment: If you remove the `@` and replace it by a proper `is_dir` check, my upvote is yours :) Bonus points for checking whether the parent directory `is_writable()` for a watertight helper function.

Comment: Using @ to suppress the errors is a performance hit. Better to check it doesn't already exist like Gumbo

Comment: Regardless of error suppression, I'm inclined to -1 for the first example.  The second is so much better that the first is pointless.

Comment: This is difficult to read code just for the point of putting it on 1 line. The accepted answer is much clearer.

Answer (score 75):

Here is something a bit more universal since this comes up on Google.  While the details are more specific, the title of this question is more universal.

```
/**
 * recursively create a long directory path
 */
function createPath($path) {
    if (is_dir($path)) 
        return true;
    $prev_path = substr($path, 0, strrpos($path, '/', -2) + 1 );
    $return = createPath($prev_path);
    return ($return && is_writable($prev_path)) ? mkdir($path) : false;
}
```

This will take a path, possibly with a long chain of uncreated directories, and keep going up one directory until it gets to an existing directory.  Then it will attempt to create the next directory in that directory, and continue till it's created all the directories.  It returns true if successful.

It could be improved by providing a stopping level so it just fails if it goes beyond the user folder or something and by including permissions.

Comment: @phazei I get a call to undefined function because of the line $return = createPath($prev_path);

Comment: Thanks @phazei :)

Answer (score 37):

A faster way to create a folder:

```
if (!is_dir('path/to/directory')) {
    mkdir('path/to/directory', 0777, true);
}
```

Comment: This would give error if there is a file named 'directory' at that path.

Answer (score 25):

Recursively create the directory path:

```
function makedirs($dirpath, $mode=0777) {
    return is_dir($dirpath) || mkdir($dirpath, $mode, true);
}
```

Inspired by Python's [`os.makedirs()`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.makedirs)

Comment: In what way is it recursive? Not in the function calls (it doesn't call itself)? What is the principle of operation? Why does work? Does mkdir do it recursively? Can you elaborate a little bit in your answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: There is some explanation in [Satish Gadhave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303372/create-a-folder-if-it-doesnt-already-exist/15075269#15075269).

Answer (score 22):

The best way is to use the `wp_mkdir_p` function. This function will **recursively** create a folder with the **correct permissions**.

Also, you can **skip folder exists condition** because the function returns:

- `true` when the directory was created or existed before
- `false` if you can't create the directory.

Example:

```
$path = 'path/to/directory';
if ( wp_mkdir_p( $path ) ) {
    // Directory exists or was created.
}
```

More: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mkdir_p/

Comment: Worth mentioning that `wp_mkdir_p()` will also return true if directory already exists, so you don't need any additional `file_exists()` checks. Also, it will do its best to set proper directory permissions. I'd always go with this function instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that it is a WordPress specific function, not a generic PHP function.  That being said, there is nothing stopping you from just copying the function from the WordPress Developers site.

Answer (score 12):

Within WordPress, there's also the very handy function [wp_mkdir_p](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mkdir_p) which will recursively create a directory structure.

Source for reference:

```
function wp_mkdir_p( $target ) {
    $wrapper = null;

    // Strip the protocol
    if( wp_is_stream( $target ) ) {
        list( $wrapper, $target ) = explode( '://', $target, 2 );
    }

    // From php.net/mkdir user contributed notes
    $target = str_replace( '//', '/', $target );

    // Put the wrapper back on the target
    if( $wrapper !== null ) {
        $target = $wrapper . '://' . $target;
    }

    // Safe mode fails with a trailing slash under certain PHP versions.
    $target = rtrim($target, '/'); // Use rtrim() instead of untrailingslashit to avoid formatting.php dependency.
    if ( empty($target) )
        $target = '/';

    if ( file_exists( $target ) )
        return @is_dir( $target );

    // We need to find the permissions of the parent folder that exists and inherit that.
    $target_parent = dirname( $target );
    while ( '.' != $target_parent && ! is_dir( $target_parent ) ) {
        $target_parent = dirname( $target_parent );
    }

    // Get the permission bits.
    if ( $stat = @stat( $target_parent ) ) {
        $dir_perms = $stat['mode'] & 0007777;
    } else {
        $dir_perms = 0777;
    }

    if ( @mkdir( $target, $dir_perms, true ) ) {

        // If a umask is set that modifies $dir_perms, we'll have to re-set the $dir_perms correctly with chmod()
        if ( $dir_perms != ( $dir_perms & ~umask() ) ) {
            $folder_parts = explode( '/', substr( $target, strlen( $target_parent ) + 1 ) );
            for ( $i = 1; $i <= count( $folder_parts ); $i++ ) {
                @chmod( $target_parent . '/' . implode( '/', array_slice( $folder_parts, 0, $i ) ), $dir_perms );
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Re *"recursively create a directory structure"*: Does this suggest vanilla PHP functions can not do it?

Answer (score 9):

I needed the same thing for a login site. I needed to create a directory with two variables.

The $directory is the main folder where I wanted to create another sub-folder with the users license number.

```
include_once("../include/session.php");

$lnum = $session->lnum; // Users license number from sessions
$directory = uploaded_labels; // Name of directory that folder is being created in

if (!file_exists($directory . "/" . $lnum)) {
    mkdir($directory . "/" . $lnum, 0777, true);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the most up-to-date solution without error suppression:

```
if (!is_dir('path/to/directory')) {
    mkdir('path/to/directory');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For your specific question about **WordPress**, use the following code:

```php
if (!is_dir(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/uploads')) wp_mkdir_p(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/uploads');
```

Function Reference: [WordPress wp_mkdir_p](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mkdir_p/). **ABSPATH** is the constant that returns WordPress working directory path.

There is another WordPress function named `wp_upload_dir()`. It returns the upload directory path and creates a folder if doesn't already exists.

```php
$upload_path = wp_upload_dir();
```

The following code is for **PHP in general**.

```
if (!is_dir('path/to/directory')) mkdir('path/to/directory', 0777, true);
```

Function reference: [PHP is_dir()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php)

Comment: For the WordPress use, the more secure way to use is [wp_get_upload_dir()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_upload_dir/) function.

Comment: @IvijanStefanStipić Can you explain why do you think that my code is insecure? I intentionally didn't use wp_get_upload_dir() function. So the user could create any folder he wants, not just uploads folder.

Comment: That function return base director and base url of the upload folder. If someone use security plugin or CDN and want to change that, it will relay to that function. I develop WP pligins arround 8 years and trust me, in the production you need to think in advance. You just need to add your custom folder and create if not exists.

Comment: Why is it different in WordPress than vanilla PHP? Is it strictly necessary? More secure? (Not rhetorical questions.)

Answer (score 3):

You can try also:

```
$dirpath = "path/to/dir";
$mode = "0764";
is_dir($dirpath) || mkdir($dirpath, $mode, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

### To create a folder if it doesn't already exist

Considering the question's environment.

- WordPress.
- Webhosting server.
- Assuming it's Linux, not Windows running PHP.

And quoting from: *[mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)*

> **bool** mkdir ( string $pathname [, int $mode = 0777 [, bool $recursive =
> FALSE [, resource $context ]]] )

The manual says that the only required parameter is the `$pathname`!

So, we can simply code:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0); 

    if(!mkdir('wp-content/uploads')){
        // Todo
    }
?>
```

### Explanation:

We don't have to pass any parameter or check if the folder exists or even pass the mode parameter unless needed; for the following reasons:

- The command will create the folder with [0755](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-755/) permission (the shared hosting folder's default permission) or [0777](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-777/), the command's default.
- `mode` is ignored on **Windows hosting running PHP**.
- Already the `mkdir` command has a built-in checker for if the folder exists; so we need to check the return only True|False ; and it’s not an error; it’s a warning only, and Warning is disabled on the hosting servers by default.
- As per speed, this is faster if warning disabled.

This is just another way to look into the question and not claiming a better or most optimal solution.

*It was tested on PHP 7, production server, and Linux*

Answer (score 3):

```
$upload = wp_upload_dir();
$upload_dir = $upload['basedir'];
$upload_dir = $upload_dir . '/newfolder';
if (! is_dir($upload_dir)) {
   mkdir( $upload_dir, 0700 );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid the `file_exists` vs. `is_dir` problem, I would suggest you to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35863753/2280418).

I tried this and it only creates the directory if **the directory does not exist**. It does not care if there is a file with that name.

```
/* Creates the directory if it does not exist */
$path_to_directory = 'path/to/directory';
if (!file_exists($path_to_directory) && !is_dir($path_to_directory)) {
    mkdir($path_to_directory, 0777, true);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go.

```
if (!is_dir('path/to/directory')) {
    if (!mkdir('path/to/directory', 0777, true) && !is_dir('path/to/directory')) {
        throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Directory "%s" was not created', 'path/to/directory'));
    }
}
```

Comment: PHPStorm (with PHP Inspections) gives exactly this suggestion ;-) btw. you can merge the outer if into the inner: if (!is_dir(...) && !mkdir(...) && !is_dir(...)) ...

Comment: @aProgger If looks better when you separate them. a lot of programmers won't merge the if statements.

Comment: It's a matter of taste. I would merge them and even kick the braces, to get an one liner. But I am curious. Would you seperate only the first !is_dir or the last one too?

Comment: Wow, out of all the answers this is the only robust one with meaningful error-handling. Congratulations, you win my Internet-points.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!is_dir('path_directory')) {
    @mkdir('path_directory');
}
```

Comment: With error suppression, there is no need in checking that directory exists

Comment: it's better to handle errors than suppress them. If this fails, you will never know why from this, and will have to research it

Comment: In highly concurrent/multithreaded environments it is advisable to suppress the error. A race condition might occur in which two or more threads will evaluate is_dir() to false and will try to create the directory. The first thread will be able to create it without any problem, but the other threads will fail to do so, because the directory already exists.

To avoid missing an actually failed directory creation you should check the existence of the directory after the call to @mkdir() again.

Answer (score 0):

We should always modularise our code and I've written the same check it below...

We first check the directory. If the directory is absent, we create the directory.

```
$boolDirPresents = $this->CheckDir($DirectoryName);

if (!$boolDirPresents) {
        $boolCreateDirectory = $this->CreateDirectory($DirectoryName);
        if ($boolCreateDirectory) {
        echo "Created successfully";
      }
  }

function CheckDir($DirName) {
    if (file_exists($DirName)) {
        echo "Dir Exists<br>";
        return true;
    } else {
        echo "Dir Not Absent<br>";
        return false;
    }
}
     
function CreateDirectory($DirName) {
    if (mkdir($DirName, 0777)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to current solutions, a utility function.

```php
function createDir($path, $mode = 0777, $recursive = true) {
  if(file_exists($path)) return true;
  return mkdir($path, $mode, $recursive);
}

createDir('path/to/directory');
```

It returns `true` if already exists or successfully created. Else it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

We can create folder using `mkdir`. Also we can set permission for it.

> ```
> Value Permission
> 0     cannot read, write or execute
> 1     can only execute
> 2     can only write
> 3     can write and execute
> 4     can only read
> 5     can read and execute
> 6     can read and write
> 7     can read, write and execute
> ```

```
<?PHP
  
// Making a directory with the provision
// of all permissions to the owner and 
// the owner's user group
mkdir("/documents/post/", 0770, true)
  
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You first need to check if directory exists `file_exists('path_to_directory')`

Then use `mkdir(path_to_directory)` to create a directory

```
mkdir( string $pathname [, int $mode = 0777 [, bool $recursive = FALSE [, resource $context ]]] ) : bool
```

More about [mkdir() here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

Full code here:

```
$structure = './depth1/depth2/depth3/';
if (!file_exists($structure)) {
    mkdir($structure);
}
```