# How do I check if a directory exists? "is_dir", "file_exists" or both?

Tags: php

I want to create a directory if it does not exist already.

Is using the `is_dir` function enough for that purpose?

```
if ( !is_dir( $dir ) ) {
    mkdir( $dir );       
}
```

Or should I combine `is_dir` with `file_exists`?

```
if ( !file_exists( $dir ) && !is_dir( $dir ) ) {
    mkdir( $dir );       
}
```

Comment: @IvoRenkema PHP also supports `or`/`and` besides `||`/`&&`.

Comment: Operator `&&` is unuseful here, because, if file doesn't exist (`!file_exists($dir) == true`), for sure it is not a directory. And if file exists, `!is_dir($dir)` will not be checked, because `!file_exists($dir)` will return `false` and `&&` operator is [short-circuit](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

Comment: In my view, the operator should be OR.

Comment: with && this works perfectly for me

Comment: It should be `if ( !file_exists( $dir ) || !is_dir( $dir) ) {
  mkdir($dir);
}`

If you put &&, will not create the directory if has a file with the same name of directory.

Answer (score 267, accepted):

Both would return true on Unix systems - in Unix everything is a file, including directories. But to test if that name is taken, you should check both. There might be a regular file named 'foo', which would prevent you from creating a directory name 'foo'.

Comment: dont forget to check if is_writable also

Comment: @Drewdin you'd want to check the parent for `is_writable` wouldn't you?

Comment: Can you provide a brief code snippet example? It would be very helpful and much appreciated.

Comment: Could you clarify why `file_exists` may be useful? It seems that checking `is_dir` should be enough

Answer (score 160):

```
$filename = "/folder/" . $dirname . "/";

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "The directory $dirname exists.";
} else {
    mkdir("folder/" . $dirname, 0755);
    echo "The directory $dirname was successfully created.";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: considering it takes post input and uses it as-is, plus makes 0777 dir, prolly not that safe at all ;P

Comment: More seriously, $dirname could be sanitized and permission could be set to 0755. Add to that some .htaccess directives. There's some further recommendations over at OWASP:  https://www.owasp.org/

Comment: `# The following directives force the content-type application/octet-stream
# and force browsers to display a download dialog for non-image files.
# This prevents the execution of script files in the context of the website:
#ForceType application/octet-stream
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
<FilesMatch "(?i)\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">
 ForceType none
 Header unset Content-Disposition
</FilesMatch>

# The following directive prevents browsers from MIME-sniffing the content-type.
# This is an important complement to the ForceType directive above:
Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff`

Comment: 766 i think will be ok for a public folder since anyone can access and write but noone can delete

Comment: When you use `mkdir` - why didn't you just pass '$filename'?

Comment: Because this answer is stupid altogether and wrong on every level. It checks if different file exists than the directory it creates (it checks at / instead of current directory).

Answer (score 26):

I think realpath() may be the best way to validate if a path exist
http://www.php.net/realpath

Here is an example function:

```
<?php
/**
 * Checks if a folder exist and return canonicalized absolute pathname (long version)
 * @param string $folder the path being checked.
 * @return mixed returns the canonicalized absolute pathname on success otherwise FALSE is returned
 */
function folder_exist($folder)
{
    // Get canonicalized absolute pathname
    $path = realpath($folder);

    // If it exist, check if it's a directory
    if($path !== false AND is_dir($path))
    {
        // Return canonicalized absolute pathname
        return $path;
    }

    // Path/folder does not exist
    return false;
}
```

Short version of the same function

```
<?php
/**
 * Checks if a folder exist and return canonicalized absolute pathname (sort version)
 * @param string $folder the path being checked.
 * @return mixed returns the canonicalized absolute pathname on success otherwise FALSE is returned
 */
function folder_exist($folder)
{
    // Get canonicalized absolute pathname
    $path = realpath($folder);

    // If it exist, check if it's a directory
    return ($path !== false AND is_dir($path)) ? $path : false;
}
```

Output examples

```
<?php
/** CASE 1 **/
$input = '/some/path/which/does/not/exist';
var_dump($input);               // string(31) "/some/path/which/does/not/exist"
$output = folder_exist($input);
var_dump($output);              // bool(false)

/** CASE 2 **/
$input = '/home';
var_dump($input);
$output = folder_exist($input);         // string(5) "/home"
var_dump($output);              // string(5) "/home"

/** CASE 3 **/
$input = '/home/..';
var_dump($input);               // string(8) "/home/.."
$output = folder_exist($input);
var_dump($output);              // string(1) "/"
```

Usage

```
<?php

$folder = '/foo/bar';

if(FALSE !== ($path = folder_exist($folder)))
{
    die('Folder ' . $path . ' already exist');
}

mkdir($folder);
// Continue do stuff
```

Comment: For anyone who comes across this, I believe that realpath caches folders when it runs, so if it's run once, then the folder is removed after that, it may not return false if run again.

Comment: so does file_exists though

Answer (score 7):

Second variant in question post is not ok, because, if you already have file with the same name, but it is not a directory, `!file_exists($dir)` will return `false`, folder will not be created, so error `"failed to open stream: No such file or directory"` will be occured. In Windows there is a difference between 'file' and 'folder' types, so need to use `file_exists()` and `is_dir()` at the same time, for ex.:

```
if (file_exists('file')) {
    if (!is_dir('file')) { //if file is already present, but it's not a dir
        //do something with file - delete, rename, etc.
        unlink('file'); //for example
        mkdir('file', NEEDED_ACCESS_LEVEL);
    }
} else { //no file exists with this name
    mkdir('file', NEEDED_ACCESS_LEVEL);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same doubt, but see the PHP docu:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php

You will see that `is_dir()` has both properties.

> Return Values is_dir
> Returns TRUE if the filename exists and is a directory, FALSE otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

```
$year = date("Y");   
$month = date("m");   
$filename = "../".$year;   
$filename2 = "../".$year."/".$month;

if(file_exists($filename)){
    if(file_exists($filename2)==false){
        mkdir($filename2,0777);
    }
}else{
    mkdir($filename,0777);
}
```

Comment: You can check on the full path and if it doesn't exist create it with mkdir recursive:
if (!file_exists($filename2)) { mkdir($filename2, 0777, true); }

Also, you're code will never create the full path if $filename doesn't exist...

Comment: This code-only answer seems to be drifting away from the scope of the question (doesn't this answer just repeat what earlier answers already said?) and should include some plain-speak that explains the snippet.

Answer (score 3):

```
$save_folder = "some/path/" . date('dmy');

if (!file_exists($save_folder)) {
   mkdir($save_folder, 0777);
}
```

Comment: Setting chmod 777 is never a good idea. 755 is sufficient for folders.

Comment: This post is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old, but still topical question. Just test with the `is_dir()` or `file_exists()` function for the presence of the `.` or `..` file in the directory under test. Each directory must contain these files:

```
is_dir("path_to_directory/.");
```

Answer (score 1):

Well instead of checking both, you could do `if(stream_resolve_include_path($folder)!==false)`. It is [slower](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19589043/1291428) but kills two birds in one shot.

Another option is to simply ignore the `E_WARNING`, **not** by using `@mkdir(...);` (because that would simply waive all possible warnings, not just the directory already exists one), but by registering a specific error handler before doing it:

```
namespace com\stackoverflow;

set_error_handler(function($errno, $errm) { 
    if (strpos($errm,"exists") === false) throw new \Exception($errm); //or better: create your own FolderCreationException class
});
mkdir($folder);
/* possibly more mkdir instructions, which is when this becomes useful */
restore_error_handler();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do

```
if(is_dir("./folder/test"))
{
  echo "Exist";
}else{
  echo "Not exist";
}
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps, particularly for a question that already has an accepted answer. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A way to check if a path is directory can be following:

```
function isDirectory($path) {
    $all = @scandir($path);
    return $all !== false;
}
```

> NOTE: It will return false for non-existant path too, but works perfectly for UNIX/Windows

Answer (score 0):

i think this is fast solution for dir check.

```
$path = realpath($Newfolder);
if (!empty($path)){
   echo "1";
}else{
   echo "0";
}
```