# mkdir function not working properly

Tags: php

I have folder hierarchy as Bucharest/Waterfall/a.php. My code snippet for making directory on server is as follows:

```
if(!is_dir($this->folder)){  
                $old_umask = umask(0);
                mkdir($this->folder, 0777);  
                umask($old_umask);
                }
                chmod($this->folder, 0777);

            // Moves current file to upload destination
            if(move_uploaded_file($current['tmp_name'],$uploadFile))
                return true;
```

All files are uploaded to the server. Now the issue is that the parent folder ,i.e. Bucharest has permission 755 while inner folder has permission 777. $this->folder has value as Bucharest/Waterfall. It gives 755 permission to Bucharest while 777 permission to waterfall. According to my code the 777 permission should also be given to Bucharest.

I have also tried chmod but all in vain. I want to give full permission to parent folder.

Comment: Try this link    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425891/check-if-directory-exists-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_dir($this->folder);` tells you that the file isn't a directory, not that it doesn't exist. and of course you can't mkdir if the directory is already there.

Also, if the directory already exists, according to the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) chmod will not do anything if the user under which php is running isn't the same as the user who owns that directory.

Comment: yes your are right but its path is Bucharest/waterfall it means it will first create Bucharest then waterfall. it is giving 777 permission to waterFall but it is giving 755 permission to Bucharest

Comment: if Bucharest already exists, the code will not do anything. Also, it will not do anything for the existing dir if the user under which php is running is not the same as the user who created this folder.

Comment: yes but if Bucharest doesnt exist then it will create Bucharest and give 755 permission

Answer (score 0):

Is the folder you are checking a subfolder already? If so, create the parent folders firts.

i.e.

```
mkdir('/tmp/test1/test2/test3/test4');
```

will fail if '/tmp/test1/test2/test3' doesn't exist