# Creating + Writing to a Text file in PHP

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite, fclose

As the title said, I am trying to use PHP to write create a text file (eventually a log file) that will be continuously updated with strings. Originally I tried something like this:

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = "John Doe\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
?>
```

And the result output was "Unable to open file!".
I was told that it could be a permissions problem so I tried this as well:

```
<?php

 $dir = '/home/Documents';

 // create new directory with 744 permissions if it does not exist yet
 // owner will be the user/group the PHP script is run under
 if ( !file_exists($dir) ) {
     mkdir ($dir, 0744);
 }

 file_put_contents ($dir.'/log.txt', 'Hello File');
?>
```

And still no luck. I am new to PHP and web server management. I am running Ubuntu 14.04LTS with lighttpd set up and I was testing it on Firefox and Chrome. I am running it with URL: localhost/index.php.

Help! I love you.

Comment: What doesn't work about the 2nd one? does it create the directory?

Comment: If it doesn't create the directory i would say it is because the directory that you are trying to create the new directory under doesn't have the permissions.

Comment: I think you need to set proper permissions because it is big problem on Ubuntu. Everytime you create a new directory you need to set its permissions. You can also do it graphically. Right click on the folder and select permissions on the window that pops up and set proper permissions.

Answer (score 1):

```
    I think you need to use chmod()

    $dir = '/home/Documents';

     // create new directory with 744 permissions if it does not exist yet
     // owner will be the user/group the PHP script is run under
     if ( !file_exists($dir) ) {
         mkdir ($dir, 0744);
     }
    // use chmod
     chmod($dir, 755);
     file_put_contents ($dir.'/log.txt', 'Hello File');
```

Comment: Additionally you can check for writable by is_writable() as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425891/check-if-directory-exists-php