# file_exists not working with localhost URL

Tags: php, file-exists

I have this piece of code in PHP:

```
if (file_exists($_POST['current_folder'])) {
    //do something
}
```

But `file_exists` always returns false. The value passed to the function is:

```
echo $_POST['current_folder']);  //This prints: http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/music
```

I also tried with different folders on the localhost. The function always returns false.

I also tried `is_dir()`. But even this function returns false with the above URL.

There are many related questions on Stack Overflow. But most of them suggest that `file_exists` only works with relative URLs. But from [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) it is clear that `http://` URLs are also supported by the `file_exists` function.

What am I missing?

Comment: use the local file path, not hte web path

Answer (score 2):

Use directory path; not web URL:

```
<?php
$filename = '/path/to/foo.txt';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
   echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
   echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
?>
```

Comment: ok thanks for the answer. Is there a way to check if a remote directory exists or not in php?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425891/how-do-i-check-with-php-if-directory-exists

Comment: I tried is_dir() also. But even it is not working with http url

Comment: There's no way to check if remote directory exists. It's **unsafe**

Answer (score 2):

Tested under windows using Apache 2.4.9.

```
<?PHP
$crl = curl_init("http://localhost/symfony2/");
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_exec($crl);

$ret = curl_getinfo($crl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($crl);

if ($ret == 200)
    echo 'File exists';
else
    echo 'File does not exist';
?>
```

It works, **just a note**, it requires trailing slash for some reason.

Code `200` means `OK` (success).