# Find out if a folder or file already exists

Tags: php, dropbox

I am using the library: [Kunnu](https://github.com/kunalvarma05/dropbox-php-sdk)

Trying to create a folder via:

```
$dbx->createFolder('/NameFolder');
```

It works.
Only when you re-update, it gives an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client
> error: POST https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/create_folder resulted
> in a 409 Conflict response: {"error_summary":
> "path/conflict/folder/..", "error": {".tag": "path", "path": {".tag":
> "conflict", "conflict": {".tag": (truncated...)

Tried to track down the error via:

```
try {
    $dbx->createFolder('/NameFolder');
} catch(Exception $e) { 
    
}
```

Did not work out.
What should I do and how do I know if a folder already exists or a file?

Comment: It's better to check if the folder already exists *beforehand* and avoid the exception.

Comment: @Itay, This is the question, how to check it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a directory exists? "is\_dir", "file\_exists" or both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425891/how-do-i-check-if-a-directory-exists-is-dir-file-exists-or-both)

Comment: @Itay, It does not work, it checks the link, in addition, authorization will also be needed there, it also looks at the availability of the link, and I need to check the folder for existence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, i do not know what kind of business, but in general, it turned out all the same, through `try-catch`, like this:

```
try {
    return $dbx->createFolder($path);
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    return false;
}
```