# mkdir() tries to create file, even with validation - PHP

Tags: php, mkdir

im trying to create a file, and the method keep giving me this warning

> Warning: mkdir(): File exists in

My code its working, but im tired of this warning now.
My code, currently is like this. Notice that $carFecha its a Date directory. Something like "2021-10-01".

```
$carFecha = "directory/to/a/date/"
if (!file_exists($carFecha)) { //If file doesnt exists
    echo $carFecha."</br>"; //This echo isnt there, but im printing it, to see what $carFecha is trying to create.
    mkdir($carFecha); //Create the file
}
```

The worst part, its that there are 4 of this codes, **but only fails when im reaching this part.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a directory exists? "is\_dir", "file\_exists" or both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425891/how-do-i-check-if-a-directory-exists-is-dir-file-exists-or-both)

Comment: @0stone0 so i have to check with is_dir() too

Comment: It depends on your use-case. PLease read the linked question. Or take a look at [`is_dir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php)

Comment: Specifically the linked question doesnt answer my own question. He is asking how to verify... I AM verifying and the mkdir its going anyways. But im going to try both, and tell you what happens.

Comment: Try removing the `/` at the end of `$carFecha`

Comment: @Barmar im gonna try it too, but why do ?

Comment: If the name exists but it's a regular file, I don't think `file_exists()` will be true when the pathname ends with `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this in a right way, you have to use `is_dir()` instead.

`ìs_dir()` - Tells whether the filename is a directory or not.

What i was trying to check, was a directory, not a file.

```
$carFecha = "directory/to/a/date/"
if (!is_dir($carFecha)) { //If DIRECTORY doesnt exists
    echo $carFecha."</br>";
    mkdir($carFecha); //Create the file
}
```