# Test if directory exists based on filename

Tags: php, mkdir

I'm aware of the PHP `file_exists` function, & `is_dir`.

I saw about a month ago, a process where you can test BOTH in one search. But I can't find it now.

> $file = "/directory/dir2/dir3/filename";

Is there a command based on the filename only - to test if the DIRECTORY exists? (without using 2-3 lines of code)

If the directory does not exist - `mkdir` (recursive). But if the directory does exist, there's no need to use `MKDIR`.

I can't find it in the [mkdir information](https://www.php.net/mkdir)

Ps: I do know the mkdir recursive function.

Comment: you need 2-3 lines of code.

Comment: so your question is you can't find the mkdir function http://nz2.php.net/mkdir right ? check php version

Comment: note: can directories be deleted? if so, checking for existence is probably futile. just try to create it.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php It is the third parameter...
If you're having trouble, you can use shell_exec with the mkdir-p command, but it is unclear whether or Linux.
Se você está com dificuldades, pode usar o shell_exec com o comando mkdir -p, mas isso é claro se or Linux.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php
http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mkdir

Comment: @sarah: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is interesting, but in the future a little more attention to the formatting (use `code` and [links](http://google.com) where appropriate, and double check grammar at least in the title) will help making your questions more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there's a good way of doing this in a particularly short block of code - but you'd struggle to get a more resilient solution than Phazei's recursive directory creation on:

[Create a folder if it doesn't already exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303372/create-a-folder-if-it-doesnt-already-exist)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!is_dir(foldername with path)) { 
  mkdir();

}
```