# PHP Copy all files from Amazon S3 to Local Server

Tags: php

I have over 1,000 images stored on Amazon S3 - now I'd like to transfer them onto my local host server. The images are in folders and are in the following structure...

```
User01
User01/old/
User01/old/01.jpg
User01/old/02.jpg
User01/old/03.jpg
User01/new/
User01/new/01.jpg
User01/new/02.jpg
User01/new/03.jpg
```

....

```
User02
User02/old/
User02/old/01.jpg
User02/old/02.jpg
User02/old/03.jpg
User02/new/
User02/new/01.jpg
User02/new/02.jpg
User02/new/03.jpg
```

.....

```
User03
User03/old/
User03/old/01.jpg
User03/old/02.jpg
User03/old/03.jpg
User03/new/
User03/new/01.jpg
User03/new/02.jpg
User03/new/03.jpg
```

I am getting the directory structure using this php code

```
$bucketName = 'my-bucket';

$fullURL = 'http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/'.$bucketName.'/';

mkdir('temp');
$s3 = new S3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY);
    if (($contents = $s3->getBucket($bucketName)) !== false) {
        foreach ($contents as $object) {
           // print_r($object);
            echo '<br/>';
            echo $fullURL.$object['name'];

            $source = $fullURL.$object['name'];
            $destination = '/temp/'.$object['name'];
            copy($source, $destination);
        }
    }
```

The list of files is echoing out correctly, but when I get to copy the files in each directory I get errors e.g.

PHP Warning:  copy(/temp/zulu/archive/2014-03-17_21-04-40/picture02.jpg): failed to open stream

How can I copy all the files from S3 without losing the file structure?

I am aware that I may use the Amazon SDK for PHP but my host doesn't want to allow me to install it unless I upgrade to a VPS which is very expensive.

**UPDATE 1**

```
mkdir('temp/');

$s3 = new S3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY);
    if (($contents = $s3->getBucket($bucketName)) !== false) {
        foreach ($contents as $object) {
           // print_r($object);
            echo '<br/>';
            //echo $fullURL.$object['name'];

            $dst_dir = substr($object['name'], 0, strrpos($object['name'], '/'));
            echo $dst_dir;
            mkdir('temp/'.$dst_dir);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Try $destination = 'temp/'.$object['name'];

Comment: Do u have the directories at destination? php copy will not create directories use mkdir to create them first.

Comment: No I do not. I would like the directories to be automatically created, or detected automatically to create the directory accordingly

Comment: You will need to modify your code. Look up for php mkdir http://www.php.net/mkdir

Comment: zulu/archive/2014-03-17_21-04-40/picture02.jpg shows you do have directories in the file name. See this for creating directories automatically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303372/create-a-folder-if-it-doesnt-already-exist and make sure to set the correct file permissions when you're creating your directories (including mkdir('temp');) since you're on a hosting service.

Comment: I would like the directories to be automatically created rather then maullay doing them. We're talking about thousands of pictures and directories.

Comment: U can modify your code and use PhP mkdir to create them. You will need to parse the file names and chk if dir exists. Create one if it doesn't. PhP copy does not create them automatically.

Comment: I tried @Ivarpoiss and the directories are being created. Unfortunately even filenames like 123.jpg is being created as a directory.

Comment: Then you need to use $dst_dir = substr($destination, 0, strrpos($destination, '/')); when the $object['name'] is a file not a directory. But I see from your ouput that the S3 class also list the directories. So all that shouln't be a concern. You can use that information to create the directory structure. If that class set's you distinguish between files and dirs of course.

Comment: @Ivarpoiss I managed to do echo the folders which is the right step into creating them. Unfortuantely e.g. User02/new/ is being created 3 times. How can I created once. Likewise, User02/old/ is being created 3 times.

Comment: Add the new version of the code to your post

Comment: I updated the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this bit of code.

```
$dst_name = trim($object['name'], '/');
$dst_dir = substr($dst_name, 0, strrpos($dst_name, '/'));
$dst_file = trim(substr($dst_name, (int)strrpos($dst_name, '/')), '/');
if(strrpos($dst_file, '.') === false) {
    if (!file_exists('temp/'.$dst_dir.'/'.$dst_file)) {
        //mkdir('temp/'.$dst_dir.'/'.$dst_file, 0777, true);
        echo 'Directory "temp/'.$dst_dir.'/'.$dst_file.'" created.<br />';
    }
} else {
    //copy($source, 'temp/'.$dst_dir.'/'.$dst_file);
    echo 'File "temp/'.$dst_dir.'/'.$dst_file.'" copied.<br />';
}
```

It doesn't handle backslashes, periods in directory names or filesnames without an extension correctly.