# Alternative to mkdir() in php?

Tags: php, mkdir

Is there another way how to make directory in php? mkdir() is not working. I have tried this:

```
 if (!file_exists('path/to/directory')) {
     mkdir('path/to/directory', 0777, true);
 }
```

from here: [Create a folder if it doesn't already exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303372/create-a-folder-if-it-doesnt-already-exist)

I have no error, no warning, code is doing nothing.

Comment: `path/to/directory` is for example. You need to enter the actual path to your directory.

Comment: Is your call to mkdir() returning a true or a false? `$result = mkdir('path/to/directory', 0777, true); var_dump($result);`

Comment: @MarkBaker, Why suggest `0777` ? Isn't that insecure ?

Comment: I know that `path/to/directory` is for example... and mkdir() is returning false.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Please read [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2303377/53114) in the linked question.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran - I suggested displaying whether a true or false was returned from the call to mkdir(), not whether OP should change any of the call arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to try:

- Make sure you have error output enabled (including those pesky E_NOTICEs)
- As others mentioned, if mkdir returns false, it's a failure. Do you have write access?
- Are you really passing 'path/to/directory'? If yes, does 'path/to/' already exist? If 'path/to/' doesn't exist, you need to pass the third bool param as true, [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) are pretty clear on what it does.