# How to use PHP mkdir function recursively to skip existing directory and to create new one?

Tags: php, mkdir

How to use PHP mkdir function recursively to skip existing directory and to create new one from the `string $pathname`

```
// works fine if directories don't exist
mkdir($root_dir . '/demo/test/one', 0775, true);

// It will throw error - Message: mkdir(): File exists
mkdir($root_dir . '/demo/test/two', 0775, true);
```

What is the solution?

Comment: What about `!is_dir`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php

Comment: In the example I am trying to create two different directories - one and two inside demo/test. So is_dir will return FALSE but mkdir will fail, as demo/test already exists.

Comment: you can't. it'll return false if the directory exists, so you'll have to test if the directory is there BEFORE you try to create it.

Comment: Got a solution in here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6205454/1616787

Comment: what about @mkdir to silence it?

Comment: Then two will never get created inside demo/test

Comment: I just tested the code in my private server and it ran fine. Both folders were created and no error message. Documentation for mkdir says the code should work. Please check if there are any permission issues with the subfolders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work as it is, the problem happens when/if you run it for the second time as per @chris85's suggestion you can check if their exists beforehand.

```php
<?php
// given
$root_dir = __DIR__;

// and you want to have these
$dirs = [
    $root_dir . '/demo/test/one',
    $root_dir . '/demo/test/tow',
    $root_dir . '/demo/test/three',
    $root_dir . '/demo/test/four',
    $root_dir . '/demo/test/and/so/on',
];

// just check if they're not exists and then create them
foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
    if (!is_dir($dir)) {
        mkdir($dir, 0775, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with `is_dir` if the directory already exists:

```
if(!is_dir($pathname)) { 
   mkdir($pathname, 0775, true);
}
```