# How to check folder or directory is available in parent folder in PHP?

Tags: php

I am using `XMPP` server in windows 7 for executing PHP script. 
I have project folder in `htdocs` which contain my projects PHP script with required bootstrap, CSS and jquery files.
I have three subfolders in the project folder as `student`, `teacher`, and `admin`.
I have one folder as the report in admin.
I am working in student folder, How to create report directory in admin folder if report folder does not exist?

I want to create folder or Director in parent folder's not in the same folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a folder if it doesn't already exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303372/create-a-folder-if-it-doesnt-already-exist)

Comment: what did you try so far? Do you have any code to show us? Did it work? Did it throw any error?

Comment: @Dragos :- Here is my code.

Comment: @Dragos :- Here is my code.`$rebuilt_dir = "../admin/report";
                  if(!is_dir($rebuilt_dir)){
                    mkdir($rebuilt_dir)
                  }`

Comment: @Dragos :- this is part of index.php which is written in student folder.

Comment: @varlogtim :- how we could up to that folder? Do you suggest me?

Comment: I would add: `if(!is_dir($rebuilt_dir) { if(!mkdir($rebuilt_dir)) { echo "Error: ".$!; } }` - This should print the error if you are getting one.

Comment: @varlogtim :- I want to check it in previous/parent folder, not in the same folder. so how could I specify path their?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the parent directory you can use the function `dirname`. In your example it would look as follows:

```
$rebuilt_dir = "../admin/report";
$parent_dir = dirname($rebuilt_dir);

if(!is_dir($parent_dir)) { 

    if(!mkdir($parent_dir))
        echo "Error creating dir: ".$!;

    if(!is_dir($rebuilt_dir)) { 
        if(!mkdir($rebuilt_dir))
            echo "Error creating dir: ".$!;

}
```