# How to export file in .dat or .txt format using php

Tags: php, csv, file, phpmyadmin, export

I have function `export_csv()`to export file as .csv format. I want to change .dat or .txt format instead of .csv

Current code:

```
public function export_csv() {
  
  if( ! $this->path) { throw new exception('unable to create xls: missing path'); }
       /** output conetnts to csv **/
       ob_start();
       $df = fopen($this->path.'.csv', 'w');
       foreach ($this->data as $row) {
       fputcsv($df, $row);
       }
      fclose($df);
      return $this->path;
}
```

I have tried below code. but .dat file was blank. The file size 0

```
public function export_dat() {
    
    if( ! $this->path) { throw new exception('unable to create xls: missing path'); }
    /** output contents to dat **/
        ob_start();
        $df = fopen($this->path.'.dat', 'w');
        foreach ($this->data as $row) {
            fwrite($df, $row);
        }
         fclose($df);
         
         return $this->path;
}
```

Thanks advance for your help.

Comment: So what does your http server's error log file say what the issue is? We cannot look into that file, only you can...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fwrite` takes a string, not an array. Try something like this:

```php
fwrite($df, implode(', ', $row));
```

Comment: Is there any way to add "\n" at end of line. The data coming in single line like USERID, NAME, AGEuserId1, ABC, 20userId2, BCD, 30userId3, EFC, 40

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62409089/how-to-add-the-line-delimiter-n-in-php

Comment: @Siva `. "\n"`?