# How to add the line delimiter(\n) in php

Tags: php, file, export

I have below code generating report with .dat file format.

```
public function export_dat() {

    if( ! $this->path) { throw new exception('unable to create xls: missing path'); }
    /** output contents to dat **/
        ob_start();
        $df = fopen($this->path.'.dat', 'w');
        foreach ($this->data as $row) {
            fwrite($df, implode('|', $row));
        }
         fclose($df);
         
         return $this->path;
}
```

And Output is

```
USERID|NAME|AGEuserId1|ABC|20userId2|BCD|30userId3|EFC|40
```

The data generated in single line. I am expecting below format:

```
USERID|NAME|AGE
userId1|ABC|20
userId2|BCD|30
userId3|EFC|40
```

Thanks advance.

Comment: `fwrite($df, implode('|', $row) . "\n");` obviously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your current code, the simplest is to just append it in the write part...

```
fwrite($df, implode('|', $row).PHP_EOL);
```

uses `PHP_EOL` for platform independance.

Or you could use [`fputcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)...

```
fputcsv($df, $row, "|");
```

Just to note that if you definitely need to use it, "\n" will work the same in the output.